# Mysql subquery optimisation with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have got a MySQL query with the subquery.
[SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d76c6/2)

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `wildberries` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `brand` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subject` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `article` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `size` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `color` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `income` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `income_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ordered` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ordered_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ordered_max_by_day` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `return_before_payment` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `return_before_payment_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sales_by_payment` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sales_by_payment_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `return` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `return_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stock` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `source_file` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `from` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `end` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `clear_article` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `file_hash` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'sha1(concat(user_id, source_file))',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `from` (`from`),
    INDEX `end` (`end`),
    INDEX `size_color_clear_article` (`size`, `color`, `clear_article`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Query is:

```
SELECT wildberries.clear_article AS clear_article, wildberries.color AS color, wildberries.size AS size, (
SELECT w2.stock
FROM wildberries w2
WHERE w2.clear_article = wildberries.clear_article AND w2.color = wildberries.color AND w2.size = wildberries.size
ORDER BY w2.from DESC
LIMIT 1) AS stock
FROM wildberries
GROUP BY clear_article , color, size
ORDER BY `from` DESC
```

This query gives me the correct value (stock for the latest product date).

But this query is too slow. I've tried to add indexes - no results.

**The main idea is: for each product (combination with clear_article, size and color) get latest 'from' and get  'stock' for it.**

Can someone give me advice - is it possible to rewrite this query without the subquery?

Updated: sample data is on the table.

Comment: don't use link olny .. add also text with sample and expected  result

Comment: There's no data, so I wouldn't expect much of a result :-( And there's really no point including irrelevant columns in the sample table structure.

Comment: Why the subquery select?

Answer (score 0):

Why the subselect to the same table, if you're retrieving the value that's already there in the first place?
A simplified version of what you've got

```
SELECT clear_article, color, size, stock
FROM wildberries
ORDER BY wildberries.from DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a big mistake in the query. I've forgotten to add GROUP BY condition. It changes all.

Comment: And if in your query we add GROUP BY condition, result in stock will be not correct. 
P.S. Sorry for incorrect question

Comment: Provide an answer and close this question, for future reference :)